# python: can't open file 'hello_world': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

I can't open a shell from the cmd promt. Pip works and i can type some commands but keep getting the error.

```
 Directory of C:\Python27

03/03/2017  08:07 PM    <DIR>          .
03/03/2017  08:07 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          DLLs
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          Doc
03/03/2017  08:07 PM    <DIR>          dojopython
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          include
03/03/2017  07:52 PM    <DIR>          Lib
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          libs
05/23/2015  10:29 AM            38,584 LICENSE.txt
05/23/2015  10:23 AM           418,960 NEWS.txt
05/23/2015  09:44 AM            26,624 python.exe
05/23/2015  09:44 AM            27,648 pythonw.exe
05/10/2015  06:01 PM            53,986 README.txt
03/03/2017  07:36 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          tcl
03/03/2017  07:23 PM    <DIR>          Tools
               5 File(s)        565,802 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  183,884,189,696 bytes free

C:\Python27>python #
python: can't open file '#': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just type `python`, and where is your `hello_world` file

Comment: C:\Python27\dojopython>  It wont let me open it with that error as well as open a shell via python #

Comment: You do not need  the `#` on the command line. Remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The syntax is:**

```
python <python script>
```

**Consider the following - foo.py exists but bar.py does not:**

```
$ ls foo.py bar.py
ls: bar.py: No such file or directory
foo.py
$
```

**Now, this throws same error as yours:**

```
$ python bar.py
python: can't open file 'bar.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$
```

**And this works:**

```
$ python foo.py
hello world!
$
```

**Note:** Typing just 'python' (without any python script) will launch an interactive shell for you with python interpreter loaded.
Also, my examples above use a Unix environment whereas yours is Windows. The same syntax still applies though.